# My custom taxonomy page is leading in 404 page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

```
function wporg_register_taxonomy_instructor()
{
    $labels = [
        'name'              => _x('Instructors', 'taxonomy general name'),
'singular_name'     => _x('Instructor', 'taxonomy singular name'),
'search_items'      => __('Search Instructors'),
'all_items'         => __('All Instructors'),
'parent_item'       => __('Parent Instructor'),
'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Instructor:'),
'edit_item'         => __('Edit Instructor'),
'update_item'       => __('Update Instructor'),
'add_new_item'      => __('Add New Instructor'),
'new_item_name'     => __('New Instructor Name'),
'menu_name'         => __('Instructor'),
];
$args = [
'hierarchical'      => true, // make it hierarchical (like categories)
'labels'            => $labels,
'show_ui'           => true,
'show_admin_column' => true,
'query_var'         => true,
'rewrite'           => ['slug' => 'instructor'],
];
register_taxonomy('instructor', ['post'], $args);
}
add_action('init', 'wporg_register_taxonomy_instructor');
```

I use this code to register a custom taxonomy with name instructor but when I click at the link that is produced by get_term_link($term->term_id) I am leading to 404 page.

Answer (score 1):

You have to re-save the permalinks when you add or change a custom taxonomy, or a custom post type.

Go to the permalinks settings page, and re-save, then go back and refresh.

Also, you don't need to specify the slug as `instructor` if the name is `instructor`, the rewrite option can be removed or just set to `true`